How to make custom accordian loooks like a standard one
I am making a custom accordian and want to apply the same CSS as the Salesoforce standard page .
Is is possible in LWC Cmp with the help of custom CSS. kindly help me.

Custom --
Expected to make look like

I am trying with the below approach but not working.
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open active-section-name={activeSections}>
                <lightning-accordion-section name='Key Information' label='Key Information' style='background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);'>

Issue -- It is applied to complete section till the bottom.

You can follow the Lightning Desing System the develop a custom accordion.
Here you can find different examples and styling hooks to modify look as per your requirements.
To change the background colour of the accordion section header use styling hook below:
:host {
--slds-c-accordion-summary-color-background: rgb(223, 223, 223);
}



Thanks @Tushar Jadav
